# Extract data from multilevel columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, full-text-search

I'm trying to extract data from an imported data frame

It has 2 levels of column names. Presently, I'm trying to select "GBP" from the first-level column names, and then only the "HIGH" column from level 2

```
Security    GBP             EUR             CHF
Field       HIGH    LOW     HIGH    LOW     HIGH    LOW
Date                        
2016-03-03  1.4194  1.403   1.0972  1.0851  0.999   0.9888
2016-03-04  1.4247  1.4105  1.1042  1.09    0.9988  0.9874
2016-03-07  1.4282  1.4132  1.1025  1.0938  1.0013  0.9922
2016-03-08  1.4274  1.4171  1.1057  1.099   0.9971  0.9897
2016-03-09  1.4241  1.4174  1.1035  1.0944  1.0035  0.9938
```

With this code below, I am able to extract the data in regard to the first level. But then, I am still stuck with the "HIGH" and "LOW" columns.

```
df[["GBP]] 

Security    GBP            
Field       HIGH    LOW    
Date                        
2016-03-03  1.4194  1.403   
2016-03-04  1.4247  1.4105
2016-03-07  1.4282  1.4132  
2016-03-08  1.4274  1.4171  
2016-03-09  1.4241  1.4174
```

Essentially, I'm asking how can I filter by the second level of the column index

Thanks

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.